# Please solve this integration $\int\sin(x^2)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral $\int\sin(x^2)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}$ doesn't have an elementary solution. But I don't understand why?
Can anyone please explain it.

Comment: Related: [Fresnel integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)

Comment: I assume you have searched for it. What results did you get? What about them did you not understand? If you don't tell us, we will just tell you something you already know, which is a waste of time.